# Change the float of 2 div on mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-float, bootstrap-4

I have two main div on my site, a left and a right.

The left one has these classes: `col-md-3 left_side`
And the right one: `col-md-9 right_side`

In the CSS file, the left_side and the right_side classes have only just some padding, no float. The floating is from the col-md bootstrap classes.

How can I do that if I am viewing the site on mobile or tablet, to change these to divs sequence? The right_side div will be the first.

I want this, because now on mobile, the left_side div is the first, and I have to scroll down a lot to view the actual page content or the product page I selected.

**Update: Whit this code, i still get the same problem.**

```
 @media (max-width: 575px) {
.left_side {
    float: right;
}
.right_side {
    float: left;
}
}
 @media (min-width: 576px) and (max-width: 767px) {
.left_side {
    float: right;
}
.right_side {
    float: left;
}
}
 @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
.left_side {
    float: right;
}
.right_side {
    float: left;
}
}
```

Comment: Mate, you need to post the **complete** code snippet that you have now. You don't wanna answers to be based on guesswork.

Comment: You can achieve this using `flex` in CSS

Comment: I added the css to my first post.

Comment: "complete" code snippet doesn't just mean css, it means COMPLETE.

Comment: Its to div, the classes are in my question, and this css.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple solution for this issue:
**Edit:** changes css
**Edit2** Using max-width instead min-width in css media query

```css
.left_side {
  background-color: red;
}
.right_side {
  float: right !important;
  background-color: blue;
}
@media (max-width: 992px) {
  .right_side {
      float: none !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-9 right_side">Right in desktop, top in mobile</div>
<div class="col-md-3 left_side">left in desktop, bottom in mobile</div>
```

Comment: Do i have to add the pull-md-right class? Now, i tryed it without that, but still the same problems.

Update: its not working with that class also.

Comment: No its not required pull-md-right class. But you have to apply "float: right !important;" to your  right_side div

Comment: @media (max-width: 992px) {
  .pull-md-right {
      float: right !important;
  }
}

If i use the media query you writed, it works, but whit is, it doesnt do anthong when i resize the screen.

Comment: I edited code please check it, And its (min-width: 992px) not (max-width: 992px)

Comment: But why min-width 992? I only need this change on mobile and tablet.

Comment: I need someting like this, but it doesnt change the float.  @media (max-width: 992px) {
  .right_side {
      float: left !important;
  }
  .left_side {
      float: right !important;
  }
}

Comment: Again i edited my code with max-width , I hope it works for you

Comment: Nothing :D You can view the site here, if you wnt: https://epitoanyagturkalo.hu/informaciok

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164338/discussion-between-nidhi-and-kisstom87).